# What does this means in this context その背中はどこか浮ついているように見えた。(MC came to the club room ,and saw her senpai is already there before her)

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

**Context : MC came to the school's drama club room ,then she saw her senpai is already there before her ,and playing with a pencil in her hand. Then she's describing her impression about her senpai from behind**

**その背中はどこか浮ついているように見えた。** (my guess but not sure: "..But looking at her back from behind , I feel like her head is floating in the cloud somewhere.")

**Appreciate if someone can help me understand correctly this part .**

──放課後。

私は演劇部の部室にやってきた。

すると、先に来ていた白石梨々紗先輩はいつものように窓際に座り忙しなく鉛筆を動かしていた。

梨々紗「うーん、こう？いやいや、こうかな？」

**悩んでいるようにも見えるけれど、その背中はどこか浮ついているように見えた。**

MC「……梨々さん、楽しそうですね」

梨々紗「きゃっ！？」

手元を覗き込むと、梨々さんは私の存在に気付き軽く顔を赤らめた。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[浮つく](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%B5%AE%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F/#jn-21347) is different from 浮く.

> ［動カ五（四）］うきうきして落ち着かなくなる。また、軽薄な感じがする。「気持ちが―・いて仕事に集中できない」「―・いた交際」

It means *to be restless, buoyant, in high spirits*.

So the latter part of the sentence literally says *Her back looked somewhat in high spirits.* Simply put, it says she radiates happiness in such a way that it is recognizable even from behind.

Comment: my jp spider sense was right lol , so basically her senpai is drawing a stage design for the club's next drama performance ,and then she's too motivated with that to the point when MC speaks to her in the next line ,she's startled because did not notice about MC's arrival in the drama club's room.

Answer (score 1):

浮つく（うわつく）（interchangeable with 上付く）

気がうきうきしておちつかない。また、軽薄な感じがする。
(From kojien dictionary 広辞苑)

Definition: ①軽薄　to be inconstant, to be frivolous. ②うきうきして落ち着かない feeling restless

This verb is composed from 浮く
It means literally “to float”
So,浮つく contains “not stable” like this meaning implicitly.